# How do I filter out videos non-embeddable videos from Youtube playlist API

Tags: ios, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, ytplayerview

I want to filter out non-embeddable videos from Youtube Playlist API like I do in search API.

I am using **videoEmbeddable=true** for search api like *"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=(searchText)&type=video&maxResults=20&videoEmbeddable=true&key=(YTApiKey)"* and it's working fine.

But how do I do the same in Playlist API?

*"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet,status&maxResults=50&playlistId=(id)key=(YTApiKey)".*

The param **videoEmbeddable=true** doesn't seem to work on playlistItems API.

Please help & thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with some extra steps. As noted, PlaylistItems does not accept that parameter and does not contain the *embeddable* data in the *status* part, so we have to make an additional call to Videos:List for it.

1. Grab all the Video IDs from your call to PlayListItems.
2. Use them in a call to [Videos:List](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) with the part 'status', up to 50 video IDs at a time.

Example for 3 video IDs:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=status&id=Ks-_Mh1QhMc%2Cc0KYU2j0TM4%2CeIho2S0ZahI&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

3. Then check each item's status for the *embeddable* field set to true.

   "status": {
       "uploadStatus": "processed",
       "privacyStatus": "public",
       "license": "youtube",
       "embeddable": true,
       "publicStatsViewable": true
   }

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done, since playlists are collection of videos and some of the videos in the collection might be embeddable and some might be for instance.

After getting playlists from the API you could make queries for videos contained in the playlist to see if a given video is embeddable or not...